# Are there any way to remove a empty text?

Tags: python

so I have this line

```
invite = re.search("discord.gg/(.*)", ctx.content).group(1)
```

This line is searching in discord chat for invites, and an invite looks like this discord.gg/82181, but sometimes someone drop it like this discord.gg/82 181, so you see its an empty space there, (.*) is that code (82181), can I make a function that automatically delete the space if it detects any? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `replace()` function.

```
invite = re.search("discord.gg/(.*)", ctx.content).group(1).replace(' ', '')
```

If the message can contain other stuff after the number, you can make `.*` more specific so it doesn't capture that.

```
invite = re.search("discord.gg/([\d ]*)", ctx.content).group(1).replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem description but I think he means he is searching raw chat messages, I could send something like
```hello click this link discord.gg/82 181 , that's your invite link```
in that case this will bring all characters after the discord link 
```82 181 , thats your invite link```

Comment: if that's not the case, then you are surely correct. as I said I cannot confirm his usecase

Comment: I took his question at face value, that the rest is always numbers, it just sometimes contains extra spaces.

Comment: @KareemEmad I added an answer that only captures numbers and spaces, then removes the spaces.